# Using React router V6 and when refresh page I get blank page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, history

I am learning ReactJs and I can't understand this problem. I find [much](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually?page=1&tab=active#tab-top) discussion about this but it's all for router lower then v6.

On localhost it works OK, but on live server it's not working. If I type this or refresh:

> https://greta.portplays.com/app/login

I get a blank white page.

I know this has something to do with history but router v6 doesn't use it the same way as other explanations.

These are my routes, nothing special:

```
import React from 'react';
import ContentLayout from './components/structure/ContentLayout';
import DashboardLayout from './components/DashboardLayout';
import AccountView from './components/DashboardLayout/views/account/AccountView';
import SearchListView from './components/DashboardLayout/views/search/SearchListView';
import DashboardView from './components/DashboardLayout/views/dashboard/DashboardView';
import NotFoundView from './components/DashboardLayout/views/errors/NotFoundView';
import CreateContentView from './components/DashboardLayout/views/creator/CreateContentView';
import SettingsView from './components/DashboardLayout/views/settings/SettingsView';
import LoginView from './components/DashboardLayout/views/auth/LoginView';
import RegisterView from './components/DashboardLayout/views/auth/RegisterView';
import SubmissionsView from './components/DashboardLayout/views/submissions/SubmissionsView';
import InboxView from './components/DashboardLayout/views/inbox/InboxView';

const routes = [
    {
        path: 'app',
        element: <DashboardLayout />,
        children: [
            { path: 'account', element: <AccountView /> },
            { path: 'search', element: <SearchListView /> },
            { path: 'dashboard', element: <DashboardView /> },
            { path: 'create', element: <CreateContentView /> },
            { path: 'submissions', element: <SubmissionsView /> },
            { path: 'inbox', element: <InboxView /> },
            { path: 'settings', element: <SettingsView /> },
            { path: 'login', element: <LoginView /> },
            { path: 'register', element: <RegisterView /> },
            { path: '*', element: <NotFoundView /> },
            { path: '/', element: <DashboardView /> },
        ],
    },
    {
        path: '/',
        element: <ContentLayout />,
        children: [
            { path: '404', element: <NotFoundView /> },
            { path: '*', element: <NotFoundView /> },
        ],
    },
];

export default routes;
```

In the package.json I added like this

`"homepage": "https://greta.portplays.com/",`

Also in the Apache server root for the app I added .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

My app is on a subdomain like this:

[image]

Comment: Seems to be working fine when local storage is cleared or `isUserAnon` set to false

Comment: If I open this "https://greta.portplays.com/app/login" in a new Chrome account browser it will open ok but when I press refresh (F5) I get a white page no error or warning just nothing. where did you get isUserAnon??

Comment: Here is the [project](https://github.com/erikswed/Greta-100-React-Web-App) if anyone feels like digging in :)

Comment: Dev tools (F12) > Application > Local Storage

Comment: You have deployed  build folder?

Comment: @GabrielBleu oh I learn this and did not know about Local storage like that. That one could manipulate `isUserAnon` like that. THANKS! The isUserAnon is set when user is signed in anonymously and when user roll change from `anon` to `user` then it's set to false simply to indicate roll change and there is nothing in the code that can make the index.html "root" tag to be empty when changing the `isUserAnon`

Comment: @VasimShaikh yes Build folder

Comment: Thanks everyone it's [working (press hard rested F5)](https://greta.portplays.com/app/search) now as expected after pointing me in the right direction . I removed `isUserAnon` logic replacing it with better code , @GabrielBleu post an answer and I will accept

Comment: @Gabriel Bleu    i have same issue.  Router gives 404 if I try to copy and paste url in new tab any one help me regarding  this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be working fine when local storage is cleared or `isUserAnon` set to false.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change in package.json file before build.

```
{
  

  "devDependencies": {},
  "homepage": "<Your domain>",
  "author": "",
 
}
```

run build command again.

```
npm run build
```

Comment: Thanks I already had the homepage tag set but not author